# C++ Operator Overloading and 'new' is working, but I'm not sure why/how

Tags: c++, object, overloading, new-operator, operator-keyword

To fully understand my query and confusion see the first TeamUp function declaring the pointer to the Enemy using new Enemy(one+two) - as you will see, these are variables referencing two other Enemy objects previously created.

Essentially I am adding to enemies together to birth a third which will take on some of the qualities of the two parent enemies.

I have overloaded the + operator in the .cpp file for the Enemy class as listed nearer the bottom of this post, however I am struggling to understand why only one Enemy object is created in this line of code since I create a pointer then allocate with 'new Enemy' and then an object is also (theoretically) returned '(one+two)' from the overloaded operator. Initially I was surprised this worked and want to understand why it is working; You will see from where I overloaded the operator that I am also returning an Enemy object in addition (as I thought) to the one created already for the pointer. :

`new Enemy(one+two)`

I would appreciate clarity on this, since I don't understand why its working, and I've researched further the new keyword and operator overloading, I'm not entirely sure why it does work, can some body help explain what is going on in the brackets (is it acting as a constructor / initialiser?), since it seems to be calling on the overloaded operator+ and not a constructor (or it is doing both). And also a bit more clarity on why this doesn't create two objects (Even if that would ultimately fail).

Essentially, those who can help me with this, will understand what I'm asking a little more than I do. Happy to read further and be redirected to some material, as always. Thank you for your patience.

The overloaded operator code is:

```
Enemy operator+(Enemy& En, Enemy& En2)
{
    //return En.strength + En2.strength; (other attempts / learning)
    Enemy birthed;
    
    birthed.strength = En.strength + En2.strength;
    birthed.health = En.health + En2.health;
    return birthed;
```

> the main code

**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Enemy.h"
#include <string>
using std::cout;
//globals

std::vector<Enemy> Enemies;

void TeamUp(Enemy &one, Enemy &two, std::string name) {
    Enemy* baby = new Enemy(one+two);
    //*baby= one+two;
    //baby->health = one + two;
    baby->Name = name;
    baby->Mum = one.Name;
    baby->Dad = two.Name;
    Enemies.push_back(*baby);
    //std::cout << "babies str and health is " << baby->strength << " and " << baby->health << std::endl;
}

void TeamUp(Enemy &one, Enemy &two) {
    Enemy *baby = new Enemy;
    //baby->health = one + two;
    baby->Mum = one.Name;
    baby->Dad = two.Name;
    Enemies.push_back(*baby);
        
    //std::cout << "babies str and health is " << baby->strength << " and " << baby->health << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    Enemy daddy("John");
    Enemy mummy("Lisa");
    daddy.info();
    
//  std::cout << "babies str and health is " << baby.health << " " << baby.strength << std::endl;
    TeamUp(mummy, daddy, "Ryan");
    TeamUp(mummy, daddy, "Jeriel");
    TeamUp(mummy, daddy);
    TeamUp(mummy, daddy);
    TeamUp(mummy, daddy);
    TeamUp(mummy, Enemies[0]);
    for (Enemy i: Enemies) {
        i.info();
    }

    cout << Enemy::amount;

    //std::cout<< "babies str and health is " << baby.health << " " << baby.strength;


}
```

Comment: Unrelated: NEVER create an object with new and then copy it without deleting it. In your example, it is useless to use new.

Comment: Can you show me where I am copying the object. Also, I will delete the objects in the destructor on the Enemy.cpp file, and not here, thanks for comments

Comment: You are creating an Enemy*, baby in TeamUp and pushing back a copy of it to the vector, as your vector is a vector of Enemys and not Enemy*, causing a memory leak.

Comment: @CaptainHatteras What would you suggest as a fix, as a best method to pop back into the vector. I've tried vector<Enemy*> but no luck.

Comment: @CaptainHatteras Is the idea to write a good move constructor? Just looking into this now, great help!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because your compiler is *very* optimized. Here is your `operator+`:

```
Enemy operator+(Enemy& En, Enemy& En2)
{
    //return En.strength + En2.strength; (other attempts / learning)
    Enemy birthed;
    
    birthed.strength = En.strength + En2.strength;
    birthed.health = En.health + En2.health;
    return birthed;
}
```

A smart compiler will see that birthed will always be returned. It therefore creates birthed in the memory space where the return value would be, avoiding a constructor. On to this line:

```
Enemy* baby = new Enemy(one+two);
```

A smart compiler will now do one of two things:

- Reserve space for an `Enemy' and call its move constructor.
- Put the result of `one+two` where the memory would be allocated.

As you can see, your compiler was able to potentially avoid two constructors.

I hope I helped.

Comment: You did help, however I can no longer ask questions for some strange reason. Thansk anyway.